# Как разбить строку без пробелов и поместить каждую подстроку в список

Tags: python

на входе : 'CoRaLiBhMnMdSmNhPbCaUUMoIr'
на выходе: ['Co', 'Ra', 'Li', 'Bh', 'Mn' 'Md' 'Sm'....] и тд

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = 'CoRaLiBhMnMdSmNhPbCaUUMoIr'
s = ''.join(' '+el if el.isupper() else el for el in s)
print(s.split())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@>>> import re
@>>> re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*', 'CoRaLiBhMnMdSmNhPbCaUUMoIr')
['Co', 'Ra', 'Li', 'Bh', 'Mn', 'Md', 'Sm', 'Nh', 'Pb', 'Ca', 'U', 'U', 'Mo', 'Ir']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'CoRaLiBhMnMdSmNhPbCaUUMoIr'
w = ''
r = []
for i in range(len(s)):
    if (s[i].isupper()):
      if(w == ''):
          w = s[i]
      else:
          r.append(w)
          w = s[i]
    else:
        w += s[i]
if(len(w)):
    r.append(w)
print(r)
```